# Don't know how to write this preg

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm making a function call to a library that is returning a malformed json array. I can work around this if I can get a preg written to extract the part that I want.

The array is a jumbled mess, but buried deep inside it is a string that looks like this:

`token=??????,`

I need to write a preg to grab the characters represented by the question marks. I wrote this, but it's not getting the part of the text that I want:

```
$token = preg_match('@^(?:token=)?([^,]+)@i', $badJson, $matches);
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:
`/token=([^,]+)/i`
and the use the first sub-match to extract the token. Being more specific is usually a good idea with regex (eg. does the token have a set length? does it only contain hex characters? etc.)

Site note: https://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/ is a great site for testing regular expressions.